# How to parse a json object into a url parameter string in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have the following json encoded object:

```
{"username":"my_username","email":"my_email","password":"12345678","confirm_password":"12345678"}
```

and I want to convert this into url string so I can use it with my REST API function for example like this one:

```
search?search=asdadd%2C+United+Kingdom&type=tutor
```

I have found many functions in javascript to do this but I haven't been able to find anything in PHP. What is the function in PHP to do this?

Comment: [decode -> http build query -> done](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: How is that json related to the url? Anyway, take a look at [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Incidentally, are you sure you want to send passwords in query strings?

Answer (score 2):

The following query string:

`?username=my_username&email=my_email&password=12345678&confirm_password=12345678`

.. will turn into:

`{"username":"my_username","email":"my_email","password":"12345678","confirm_password":"12345678"}`

If you use `json_enconde`.

To reverse the process, you need to use `json_decode` as well as `http_build_query`.

First, turn the JSON into an associative array with `json_decode`:

```
$json = '{"username":"my_username","email":"my_email","password":"12345678","confirm_password":"12345678"}';

$associativeArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now use `http_build_query` with the new associative array we've built:

```
$queryString = http_build_query($associativeArray);
```

Result: `username=my_username&email=my_email&password=12345678&confirm_password=12345678`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.